# Bold and underline just part of a string

Tags: vba, ms-word

So... I have this form where people select different controls (We call safety measures controls, these are not content controls) from a listbox and add them to a list. This is in a repeating table. Each control has a heading label (either "engineering" "administrative" or "PPE" that I want to make bold and underlined but I want the options selected in the listboxes to be in normal formatting.
the portion of code that is printing this to the document looks like this:

```
  
    Set tableSequence = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set NewRow = tableSequence.Rows.Add
 
NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Text = "Engineering: " & MyString3 _
        & vbCrLf & "Administrative: " _
        & MyString4 & vbCrLf _
        & "PPE: " & MyString5
```

I want the words Engineering, Administrative, and PPE to be bold and underlined, and the items represented by the MyString objects to appear in standard formatting. Thank you.

The string portion is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim tableSequence As Table
    Dim NewRow As Row
    Dim MyString5 As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim var3
    Dim p As String
    Dim M As Long
    
    For var3 = 0 To ListBox7.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox7.Selected(var3) = True Then
    MyString5 = MyString5 & ListBox7.List(var3)
    v = Split(MyString5, ",")
    p = ""
    For M = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    p = p + v(M)
    If M Mod 3 = 2 Then
    p = p + vbCr
    Else
    p = p + ","
    End If
Next M
p = Left(p, Len(p) - 1)
Debug.Print p
End If
```

sorry for leaving that out

Comment: Where is the MyString object in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to format a part (or multiple parts) of a Cell's Value in a Word table:**

I have to admit i am not very fond of Word VBA, but i stitched this Sub together for you and it works in my test document. Adjust it to your needing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub asd()
Dim tableSequence As Table
Set tableSequence = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Dim NewRow As Row
Set NewRow = tableSequence.Rows.Add

NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Text = "Engineering: asd" & vbCrLf & "Administrative: vvv" & vbCrLf & "test" & vbCrLf & "PPE: blabla"
NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Bold = False
NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Underline = False

Dim keywordArr As Variant
keywordArr = Array("Engineering:", "Administrative:", "PPE:")

Dim keyword As Variant
Dim myRange As Variant
Dim startPos As Integer
Dim endPos As Integer
Dim length As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each keyword In keywordArr

    Do While InStr(1, myRange, keyword) = 0
        Set myRange = NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Paragraphs(i).Range
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    startPos = InStr(1, myRange, keyword)
    startPos = myRange.Characters(startPos).Start
    length = Len(keyword)
    endPos = startPos + length
    
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(startPos, endPos)
    With myRange.Font
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = True
    End With
Next keyword

End Sub
```

**Below is a solution for the same thing in Excel:**

First off you would have to write the text into the cell just like you already do.

Next would be to find the position of your keywords in the cell's value + the length of your keywords like so

```
startPos = Instr(1, NewRow.Cells(5), "Engineering:")
length = len("Engineering:")
```

Then you can set up the Font of the found substring via `Range.Characters.Font`

```
NewRow.Cells(5).Characters(startPos, Length).Font.Bold = True
NewRow.Cells(5).Characters(startPos, Length).Font.Underline = True
```

Now the elegant way would be to have an array of keywords and iterate through them to change the font for all them

```
Dim keywordArr As Variant
keywordArr = Array("Engineering:", "Administrative:", "PPE:")

Dim keyword As Variant
Dim startPos as Integer
Dim length as Integer

For Each keyword In keywordArr
    startPos = InStr(1, NewRow.Cells(5), keyword)
    length = Len(keyword)

    With NewRow.Cells(5).Characters(startPos, Length).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = True
    End With
Next keyword
```

Comment: I like the elegant solution but I end up with an error that keyword in the `For Each keyword` is undefined variable

Comment: That happened most likely because you have the Option Explicit Statement in the Module, which forces to explicitly declare every variable (Which is totally fine and even encouraged!). I updated the answer to include the declaration for keyword.

Comment: Would I dimension the StartPos Object as Integer?

Comment: @Michael Miller yes!

Comment: I'm getting an error now "compile error Method or data member not found" and it highlights the word characters in the With NewRow.Cells(5) line. is this a conflict with my NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Text line?

Comment: I just realized you asked for Word and i was answering for Excel. I will to add the Word solution to this to my Answer

Comment: That worked beautifully, plus your answer had the added effect of helping me to understand a critical issue I was having in my coding. Thank you so much!